# C# - How can I get access to a List which is inside a method, from another method?

Tags: c#, list, methods

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{   
     public void CreateList()
     {
         List<IRentable> allItems = new List<IRentable>()
        {
            new VideoBook(06841) {Titel = "Community", Rented = true, GenreType = Genre.Comedy, Actor = AllPeople.ElementAt(0)},
            new AudioBook(11585) {Titel = "Deutsch für Dummies", Rented = false, GenreType = Genre.Educational, Author = AllPeople.ElementAt(1)},
            new VideoBook(50862) {Titel = "Interstellar", Rented = false, GenreType = Genre.ScienceFiction, Actor = AllPeople.ElementAt(2)},
            new AudioBook(98065) {Titel = "The Slim Shady LP", Rented = false, GenreType = Genre.Music, Author = AllPeople.ElementAt(3) },
        };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateList();
    }
```

here I need to make a new method (a SEARCH Button that I take from the Form)where I can access to "allitems" elements

```
    private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        new List<IRentable> SearchResultItems();
        var a = titleTextBox.Text;

        // here I can't access to allitems

        foreach (var elem in allitems)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. That's a local variable, it's gone the moment you leave `CreateList`.

Comment: define `allItems` as a property instead of a local variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to define the `newItems` list in the *class* scope, not the function scope, so you can access it anywhere within the class.

I suggest you read about variable scopes, [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/) and [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx#:%7E:text=What%20are%20Variable%20Scopes%3F,entire%20method%20after%20the%20declaration.) might be good starting points.

Here is what your code would look like, if you define newItems in the class scope of Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{   
    // Notice that this variable is defined outside of functions, but its 
    // value has ben set inside CreateList(), so before CreateList() is
    // called, this variable contains null.
    List<IRentable> allItems;
    
    public void CreateList()
    {
        allItems = new List<IRentable>()
        {
            new VideoBook(06841) {Titel = "Community", Rented = true, GenreType = Genre.Comedy, Actor = AllPeople.ElementAt(0)},
            new AudioBook(11585) {Titel = "Deutsch für Dummies", Rented = false, GenreType = Genre.Educational, Author = AllPeople.ElementAt(1)},
            new VideoBook(50862) {Titel = "Interstellar", Rented = false, GenreType = Genre.ScienceFiction, Actor = AllPeople.ElementAt(2)},
            new AudioBook(98065) {Titel = "The Slim Shady LP", Rented = false, GenreType = Genre.Music, Author = AllPeople.ElementAt(3) },
        };
    }
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateList();
    }

    private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // You can access allItems variable here, because both CreateList() 
        // and searchButton_Click() functions are within the class scope,
        // where the variable was defined.

        foreach (var elem in allItems)
        ...
    }
}
```